# Access partial's components in PHP section in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I need to access and modify a component that I am loading in a partial in its own PHP section.

Usually I load components in pages and I can access them using `$this->page->components['exampleComponent']` in the PHP section.
But when the component is loaded in a partial then it is not there.

I have tried onStart and onEnd to test if its due to October's lifecycle but they are never added to page components.

How can I access it then?

```
description = "Sample Partial"

[someComponent exampleComponent]
code = "header-menu"

==
<?php
function onStart(){

   // Need to access partial's component here
   $exampleComponent = ??? 
}
?>
==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `controller object` for that as It manages `partial stack`.

> In docs they mentioned that partial has different `life-cycle then pages` so may be that is the reason it's components are not in `page` object

There is convenient method in controller `findComponentByName('component-name')` to search component from `page or partial`

So you can use `below code` to get your component.

```php
description = "Sample Partial"

[someComponent exampleComponent]
code = "header-menu"

==
<?php
function onStart(){
   // Need to access partial's component here 
   $exampleComponent = $this->controller->findComponentByName('exampleComponent');
   //           USE controller obj ^ and this method ^
}
?>
```

It should work.

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you Hardik, great answer... I did not know that I could get it that way. Works like a charm.

Comment: sure, I am glad it helped you :)